# Magento SOAP API V2

Tags: php, mysql, api, magento, soap

Having issues importing large data using a loop.

here is the code:

```
<code>
while($rows = oci_fetch_array($oraclesql, OCI_BOTH)){

            $manu = ucfirst($rows[0]);


$attributeCode = "manufacturer";
$label = array (
   array(
    "store_id" => array("0"),
    "value" => $manu
   )
  );

$data = array(
   "label" => $label,
   "order" => "0",
   "is_default" => "0"
  );

$orders = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeAddOption($sessionId, $attributeCode, $data); 

}
</code>
```

so bascially I am importing manufacturers from an Oracle table, but it stops importing after a while, no errors that i can see. There is about 750 records i need to import.

I have upped the ram and cache on MYSQL and PHP increased timeout session on Magento.

Comment: is there any information at logs, Apache, mysql for example?

Comment: insert thit to the top of your script and run again, should display errors: 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Doesn't display errors, and now i cant import more than 10 records, I  really can't explain it.... I will see if there are any logs

Comment: I just got this error Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds, i'm adding this ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1); see if it works

Comment: Ok i think problem solved, it didn't timeout it was just the max execution time !!!!

Comment: Next time try to use CLI, not browser based running scripts

Comment: ok thanks, I will try, just been learning how to use Magento